# Warning:Constant "item'' inferred to have type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type'),

Tags: swift

Why is this warning :
Constant 'item' inferred to have type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type'), which may be unexpected

```
func registerCellWithArr(classInstanceArr: Array<AnyClass>, resuseIndentifierArr: Array<String>?){
    if classInstanceArr.count == resuseIndentifierArr?.count {
        for (index,item) in classInstanceArr.enumerated() {
            self.register(item, forCellReuseIdentifier: resuseIndentifierArr![index])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `register` expects a specific type I presume. When you declare a parameter to be Array<AnyClass> then the compiler assume exactly that, an array that can contain objects of _any_ class.